# location of ejb-jar and weblogic-ejb-jar for ANT build?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, ejb, weblogic-10.x

I am building an EJB Project where I am creating a simple MDB that recieves a JMS message and prints it using Weblogic.

I am using ANT to build the JAR file and deploy that JAR as a module to Weblogic. I use no special ANT tasks and build the code as a normal JAR.

This process completes smoothly but the EJB doesn't read the message from the Queue. I doubt if I have put the ejb-jar and weblogic-ejb-jar under the correct folder.

My folder structure looks like below

1. Project Folder
2. Project Folder/src/package/EJBClass
3. Project Folder/xmls : I copy the XMLs here
4. Project Folder/war/classes
5. Project Folder/war/lib

As you see I am using a normal Java project to build the JAR. Is the directory structure wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you suspect that the location of the XML files is incorrect?  Where are they located if you inspect the JAR file?  What does your Ant script look like?

Comment: Why are you using ANT. It is much easier to build EARs, EJB-JARs and WARs with Maven.

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs? Have you turned up debug? You're deploying as an exploded directory or a ear/war file? See examples like: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1952